# Page not found (404) Request Method: POST Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/login/

Tags: python, django, authentication

I stored the user registration details in the database, but when I attempt to log in with the entered data, it is displaying the following message.

[image: Error]

Here is `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns=[

    path('',views.index,name='index'),
    #path('counter',views.counter,name='counter'),
    path('register/',views.register,name='register'),
    path('login/',views.login,name='login.html'),
    path('logout/',views.logout,name='logout.html'),
    path('post/<str:pk>',views.post,name='post.html')
      #path('',views.display_records,name='table.html'),
]
```

Here is `views.py`

```
def login(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        username=request.POST['username']
        password=request.POST['password']
        user=auth.authenticate(username=username,password=password)
        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request,user)
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            messages.info(request,'Invalid User Login')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        return render(request,'login.html')
```

Here is `login.html`

```
<h1>Login Now</h1>
<style>
    h3{
        color: red;
    }
</style>
{% for message in messages %}
<h3>{{message}}</h3>
{% endfor %}
<form action="login/" method='POST'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p>Username</p>
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username"/>
    <p>Password</p>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password"/>
    <br>
    <br>

    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

After completion of registration. It is not redirecting to login page, but instead showing this.

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

In the urls/path that you've defined, there's not /login/login only **/login**.

Please try changing the action from:

```html
<form action="login/" method='POST'>
```

To this:

```html
<form action="/login" method='POST'>
```

Comment: The blank space is for home page

Comment: I've edited the answer with its proper test on my end and this should solve your issue :)

Comment: Thank you. I rectified the mistake is with form action

Comment: I wrote "login" instead this{% url 'login.html' %}.Now it is working